# Font organizer that uses crowdsourcing to tag?

Tags: font-management

I use FontAgent (7.1.2) for font management and I like it but I have a lot of fonts and organizing them is a nightmare. I've set up folders for my favorites and started creating others like "handwriting" or "ornaments" but it's not helpful enough since I don't have time to go through all of them or keep it up to date. FontAgent offers Smart Sets but (from what I can tell) you make Smart Sets for bold fonts or monospace but it wouldn't help with script fonts or even sans serif.

Is there a font manager that uses tags or meta data from other sources to help organize fonts?

Thanks!

Comment: Great idea. I am using MyMovies Pro 3 app to organize my films. And I can contribute data and corrections to the huge database. All users can. You should sell this idea to the developers of your FontAgent: just let users submit extra tags and corrections.